# Android ImageView Transparent where an image is not shown

Tags: android, imageview

I have an ImageView which shows bitmaps. The ImageView is setup as this:

```
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);               
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);        
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);                
linearLayoutInner.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
linearLayoutInner.addView(imageView);
```

This means that the bitmap shown does not always go to edges vertical/horizontally. Currently the color black is just shown in areas where the bitmap is not drawn which looks a bit ugly.

I have another "root" LinearLayout that has a background image set which shows through correctly on other controls on the activity. I would like this background image to also show through around the drawn bitmaps in the imageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should try to make the imageView background color to transparent :

```
imageView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of this line `imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);`
use `imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);`

Comment: I want the bitmap scale preserved.

Comment: LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);    change this attribute to wrapcontent

Comment: But I still want the image size maximized, I just do not want it scaled incorrectly in the process. Anyhow, the solution given by Guian worked. I will stille give your initial suggestion a vote as thanks :)